Cómo solucionar el error -- > Could not resolve dependency peer @angular/animations@"^15.0.0" from ngx-bootstrap@10.3.0?
Tengo el siguiente proyecto con estas versiones

al subir un cambio, me marca el sigiente error en Jenkins

npm ERR! While resolving: ngx-bootstrap@10.3.0 npm ERR! Found:
@angular/animations@10.2.5 node_modules/@angular/animations
@angular/animations@"~10.2.5" from the root project peer
@angular/animations@"^10.0.0 || ^11.0.0-0" from
@angular/material@10.2.7 npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/material npm
ERR!     @angular/material@"^10.2.5" from the root project npm ERR!
peer @angular/material@"10.2.7" from
@angular/material-moment-adapter@10.2.7 npm ERR!
node_modules/@angular/material-moment-adapter npm ERR!
@angular/material-moment-adapter@"^10.2.5" from the root project npm
ERR!       1 more (cbmx-online) npm ERR!     1 more (cbmx-online) npm
ERR!   1 more (@angular/platform-browser)
[2024-06-17T19:31:09.651Z] npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency: npm ERR! peer
@angular/animations@"^15.0.0" from ngx-bootstrap@10.3.0 npm ERR!
node_modules/ngx-bootstrap npm ERR!   ngx-bootstrap@"^10.2.0" from the
root project npm ERR!  npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency:
@angular/animations@15.2.10 npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!   peer @angular/animations@"^15.0.0" from
ngx-bootstrap@10.3.0 npm ERR!   node_modules/ngx-bootstrap npm ERR!
ngx-bootstrap@"^10.2.0" from the root project

y estas versiones tengo el el package.json
{
  "name": "derivatives",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "docs": "compodoc -p tsconfig.doc.json"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.2.5",
    "@angular/cdk": "^10.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "~10.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "~10.2.5",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.2.5",
    "@angular/material": "^10.2.5",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^10.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "~10.2.5",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.10.3",
    "cbmx-online": "file:./cx-online-components/dist/cx-online/cx-online-0.0.1.tgz",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "jquery": "^3.6.4",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^10.2.0",
    "ngx-currency": "^1.5.2",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.7.3",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1002.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.2.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.2.5",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.19",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.16",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.5.0",
    "ng-mocks": "^10.2.5",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  }
}

pero si checo la ruta node_modules/ngx-bootstrap estan estas versiones

{   "name": "ngx-bootstrap",   "version": "10.3.0",   "description":
"Angular Bootstrap",   "author": "Dmitriy Shekhovtsov
valorkin@gmail.com",   "license": "MIT",   "schematics":
"./schematics/collection.json",   "peerDependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^15.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^15.0.0",
"@angular/common": "^15.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "^15.0.0",
"rxjs": "^6.5.3 || ^7.6.0"   },   "dependencies": {
"tslib": "^2.3.0"   },

qué debo de hacer para emparejar las versiones? o para solucionar este error

La forma fácil es poner la versión de forma manual en el package.json, borrar los npm_modules y luego instalar otra vez. Tienes que checar sobre que versiones corre lo que no es de @angular porque cuando dejes una sola versión puede ser que no funcione o tengas que actualizar y reescribir el código.

Has subido la versión de angular cerca de esta fecha??

por si no lo haces, versiona tu package.lock antes era mala práctica, ahora es lo recomendado
